# Getting the object type that fired itemStateChanged

Tags: java, swing

I was wondering how I could check what object fired the itemStateChanged.

Let's say  I have a checkbox and a dropdown. Both connected to the same itemStateChanged. In there I would like to first decide what object that was changed and then execute my code depending on the object.

How can I do this? I was thinking about this:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == JComboBox) {
        // Do code
    }
    if(e.getSource() == JDropDown) {
        // Some other code
    }
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work since JDropDown and JCheckBox are objects, not variables.

Comment: you can check for the instances of these classes which you created

Comment: You can use `instanceof`, or try type casting the event source.

Comment: That code wouldn't compile, unless there is a field named JCheckBox and a field named JDropDown. Use the actual field names referencing the checkbox and the dropdown, and you'll have your solution. A much better way would be to use two different listeners.

Comment: `But that obviously doesn't work since JDropDown and JCheckBox are objects` - and JDropDown is a not a component. Use real component names when asking a question to avoid confusion.

Comment: @camickr it was not on purpose. I tend to mix them up most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same action for all JCheckBox and the same action for all JDropDown elements in your GUI you can use the following code:

```
if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {
    // Do code
}
else if (e.getSource() instanceof JDropDown) {
    // Some other code
}
```

If you only want to have specific actions for particular elements of your GUI, you need to keep the instances of these elements e.g. as members of the class and check the source against each of them:

```
if (e.getSource() == checkbox1) {
    // Do code
}
else if (e.getSource() == checkbox2) {
    // do other code
}
else if (e.getSource() == dropDown1) {
    // Some other code
}
...
```